# request body is undefined when trying to POST in express

Tags: node.js, express, post, routes

For some reason, request body is undefined when trying to make a post request:

here is my router:
`router.route("/").post(schoolController.createSchool);`

here is what I put in schoolController for createSchool:

```
exports.createSchool = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body);
    // return undefined

    const newSchool = await School.create(req.body);

    res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      data: {
        school: newSchool,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
      message: err,
    });
  }
};
```

adding on, I am following jonas's nodejs course on udemy, and he has almost the exact thing as this, except its for handling tour requests instead of school

Comment: maybe some problem with the config of parser you are using. With the current details in your question, its impossible to tell what the reason for it to be undefined may be

Comment: Did you add body-parser middleware?
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Comment: no what is body parser middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing here is likely that you have not configured the body-parser middleware correctly. The normal `req` will not contain any property by the name `body`. Only once the request passes through the body-parser middleware, the `body` key will be added to the `req`. You can try console logging `req`. If the request is logged correctly, it is more than likely that you need to look into configuring you bodyparser middleware correctly before you can use `req.body` in your code.